# How best to implement a property where the setter can only be called once?

Tags: python, properties, python-decorators

I trying to implement a class property where the setter can only be called once and am wondering how best to achieve this ? And how to make it most 'pythonic'?

Options I have considered:

1. Subclass and extend the builtin `property`.
2. Decorate the setter of a property.
3. Add an attribute which persists how often each setter has been set.

Any other ideas?

And suggestions how to best implement?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the use case for this?

Comment: regarding use case:  I use properties extensively to perform data validation of user configuration values via setters. These properties are initially set in the constructor and most of them can be changed at runtime - so these are normal properties and the validation rules are easily visible in each setter.  

However, some configuration values cannot be changed at runtime, so the choices were to deviate from the property concept and set those during instantiation, or to introduce the SetOnceProperties.

I find it better if the pattern is always the same, ie. employ properties throughout.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using it a lot, along with other `property` functionality, subclassing property is appropriate.

It is a bit tricky, due to the way property works -  when one calls
`@prop.setter`, a new instance of the property is created. The subclass bellow will work.

```
class FuseProperty(property):
    def setter(self, func):
        def fuse(instance, value):
            name = f"_fuse_{self.fget.__name__}"
            if not getattr(instance, name, False):
                func(instance, value)
            setattr(instance, name, True)
        return super().setter(lambda instance, value: fuse(instance, value))
```

Here is it in use.

```
In [24]: class A:
    ...:     @FuseProperty
    ...:     def a(self):
    ...:         return self._a
    ...:     @a.setter
    ...:     def a(self, value):
    ...:         self._a = value
    ...:

In [25]: a = A()

In [26]: a.a = 23

In [27]: a.a
Out[27]: 23

In [28]: a.a = 5

In [29]: a.a
Out[29]: 23
```

However, if this "fuse" property is all you need, and no other code is being added to the getters and setters, it can be much simpler: you can create a brand new "Descriptor" class, using the same mechanisms used by `property` - this can be much better, as your "fuse" properties can be built in a single line, with no need for a setter and getter methods.

All that is needed is a class with `__get__` and `__set__` methods - we can add `__set_name__` to get the new property name automatically (which  `property` itself does not, so we get the name from the `fget` method above)

```
class FuseAttribute:
    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.name = name
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if instance is None:
            return self
        return getattr(instance, f"_{self.name}")
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if not getattr(instance, f"_fuse_{self.name}", False):
            setattr(instance, f"_{self.name}", value)
        # add an else clause for optionally raising an error
        setattr(instance, f"_fuse_{self.name}", True)
```

And using it:

```
In [36]: class A:
    ...:     a = FuseAttribute()
    ...:

In [37]: a = A()

In [38]: a.a = 23

In [39]: a.a
Out[39]: 23

In [40]: a.a = 5

In [41]: a.a
Out[41]: 23
```

Comment: FYI I implemented the simple FuseProperty and it generally works - but it fails with a 'maximum recursion depth exceeded' error when used in conjunction with __getattr__

Comment: Ok found the reason:  the lambda function is intercepted by __getattr__, so one has to check for the attribute name starting with _fuse and return False if so.

Answer (score 1):

Properties in Python are just [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-descriptor), and it's relatively easy to [implement  your own](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors) that does exactly what you want:

```
class SetOnceProperty:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.storage_name = '_' + name

    def __get__(self, obj, owner=None):
        return getattr(obj, self.storage_name)

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        if hasattr(obj, self.storage_name):
            raise RuntimeError(f'{self.storage_name[1:]!r} property already set.')
        setattr(obj, self.storage_name, value)

    def __delete___(self, obj):
        delattr(obj, self.storage_name)


class Test:
    test_attr = SetOnceProperty('test_attr')

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.test_attr = value*2  # Sets property.


test = Test(21)
print(test.test_attr)  # -> 42

test.test_attr = 13  # -> RuntimeError: 'test_attr' property already set.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is simple enough and more general. A decorator for a function to be called only once, and ignore subsecuent calls.

```
def onlyonce(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def decorated(*args):
        if not decorated.called:
            decorated.called = True
            return self.func(*args)
    decorated.called = False
    return decorated
```

use like this

```
class A:
    @property
    def x(self):
        ...
    @x.setter
    @onlyonce
    def x(self, val):
        ...
```

Or you can define a descriptor:

```
class Desc:
    def __get__(self, inst, own):
        return self._value

    def __set__(self, inst, value):
        if not hasattr(self, _value):
            self._value = value
```

And use like this:

```
class A:
    x = Desc()
```

Comment: @onlyonce fails with following error: NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Comment: Same here.  Just removed the `self` and it was good to go.  In my case I needed it for a singleton so the decorator worked out well for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have often preferred this way; "explicit is better than implicit":

```
class MyError(Exception):
    ...

NOT_SET = object()

class C:

    def set_my_property(self, spam, eggs, cheese):
        """This sets the property.
        If it's already set, you'll get an error. Donna do dat.
        """
        if getattr(self, "_my_property", NOT_SET) is NOT_SET:
            self._my_property = spam, eggs, cheese
            return
        raise MyError("I said, Donna do dat.")

    @property
    def my_property(self):
        return self._my_property
```

Testing:

```
c=C()
c.set_my_property("spam", "eggs", "cheese")
assert c.my_property == ("spam", "eggs", "cheese")

try:
    c.set_my_property("bacon", "butter", "coffee")
except MyError:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the [`attrs` project](https://pypi.org/project/attrs/) would be helpful for your use case. You can realize ["frozen" attributes](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/api.html#attr.setters.frozen) in the following way:

```py
import attr


@attr.s
class Test:
    constant = attr.ib(on_setattr=attr.setters.frozen)


test = Test('foo')
test.constant = 'bar'  # raises `attr.exceptions.FrozenAttributeError`
```

Note that it also supports validators via `@constant.validator` (see the example at the end of [`attr.ib` docs](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/api.html#attr.ib)).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, the attrs project is very interesting.  I may use it in future.

Answer (score 0):

I would call a secondary method to set the value and make the method replace itself.

```
@x.setter
def x(self, value):
    self._set_x(value)
def _set_x(self, value):
    self._x = value
    self._set_x = lambda v: 0
```

Also you can use a decorator like this:

```
def once_setter(property):
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapper(self, value):
            func(self, value)
            setattr(self, func.__name__, lambda v:0)
        property.setter(lambda self, value: getattr(self, func.__name__)(value))
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

and then use it like this

```
@once_setter(x)
def _x_setter(self, value):
    self._x = value
```

Note that the name of the setter you define has a different name from the property.

The decorator wraps the setter, and set the property setter to a lambda function which call the wrapper.

In turn the wrapper call your setter and then replace itself by a dummy function.

Note that you can revert the replacing by deleting the `_x_setter` attribute